# map returning map object and converting it to list removes all elements in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

Just learned that the object returned from `map()` doesn't hold up once it has been used in a `in` expression or it was converted into a list.

What is causing `b` to get emptied at the end?

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = map(lambda x: x, a)
>>> b
<map object at 0x104d8ccc0>
>>> list(b)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(b)
[]
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the englightenment. Btw, isn't it more natural `map` returning the same collection(type)? Is there any merit in addition to some gain in performance of iteration immediately following it?

Answer (score 3):

`map` outputs an iterator that applies a function (`lambda x: x`) over some iterators (`a`). As a result, `b` is an iterator. When calling `list(b)` for the first time, the iterator `b` is called several times until it reaches to its end. Afterward, `b` is an iterator which does not have any item left to produce. That's why when you call `list(b)` for the second time, it outputs an empty list.

Comment: OK. it is `iterator` not iterable as I expected. Though not sure about its design idea, it is just as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for `map` specifies that it returns an "iterator", not an "iterable".  Python defines an iterator to [loop exactly once with no repetition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__); once the end is reached then it will never return another item.

The second execution of `list(b)` attempts to build a list from an iterator that is already at the end, so it returns no items and an empty list is constructed.

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you are calling `list(b)` you are using the iterator in it and then clearing the variable `b` if you want to store `b` as a `list` use
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = list(map(lambda x: x, a))
    print(b)

> > > [1, 2, 3]
> > >           print(*b)
> > >       1 2 3
> > >       Hope this helped.

EDIT: Fixed My Mistake.

Comment: Calling `list(b)` doesn't assign to anything.